# Checking sqlite connection error in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to a local sqlite database.

This is the code I am using -

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///Latencydb.db')
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(db)
```

No exceptions are raised even when the file does not exist. Even `db.connect()` does not throw any exceptions.

Is there a way to check if the database connection succeeded? (Other than checking for the existence of a particular table in the database?)

I'm using sqlite 3.7.7 and sqlalchemy 0.6.8 on Python 2.7.2 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Have you considered that it might be creating the sqlite db file if it doesn't exist? That would go some way towards explaining the lack of exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. I was looking for a switch or argument for an 'open-only' mode, but I couldnt find that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Python versions < 3.4 (including Python 2.7) you can't prevent SQLite from creating the file for you when you connect to a SQLite database file that doesn't yet exist.

So on older Python versions you'll have to use different means to test for the existence of the file first. A simple [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) should suffice:

```
import os.path

database = '/path/to/database.db'
if not os.path.exists(database):
    raise ValueError('Invalid database path: %s' % (database,)
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///' + database)
```

On newer Python versions, the `sqlite3` library supports the [SQLite URI syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html), so you can specify a `mode=rw` parameter to disable the default `rwc` (read-write-create) mode, provided you set `uri=True` on the `sqlite3.connect()` call.

SQLAlchemy doesn't support SQLite URI parameters (yet), but you can make use of the [`creator` parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator) to pass in the URI flag and your own connection string:

```
import sqlite3

uri = 'file:/path/to/database.db?mode=rw'

creator = lambda: sqlite3.connect(uri, uri=True)

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:////', creator=creator)
```

Comment: ok.. this is really a prototype code.. I need to use a mysql database ultimately.. However if this is the only way it works for SQLite, i suppose it will have to do..

Comment: what if your argument is an SQLAlchemy database URL, or a SQLite in-memory DB? doesn't' seem right that we have to parse the argument in order to check if the file exists... I'm looking for some SQLAlchemy option to _not create_ the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @jjmontes: I've updated the answer to show how to do this using a SQLite3 `?mode=rw` parameter.

Comment: This is great. For my use case, it'd be great if SQLAlchemy leveraged this and introduced some explicit way to avoid file creation for DB drivers for which this makes sense (in my use case, it could be any database system, so I'll still need to check first whether the driver is sqlite or not). Also, very glad to be answered by a master: kudos to you and thanks!